# Separating digits in decimal representation of integer

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to take user input entered as an integer, for example `(45697)`, and store the first two digits in an array, vector, or something else such as `( 4 5 6 9 7 )`, so that I could then use some function call to check for the first two values `(4 5)` and perform calculations on them.

The Problem: I don't know how to store the recover those first two values.

Is there a simple function call? Or would I have to store the input first as any array and then extract the first two values, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using conversions to/from strings:

```
>> x = 45697; % or whatever positive value
>> str = num2str(x);
>> y = [str2num(str(1)) str2num(str(2))]

y =

     4     5
```

This assumes that the number `x` is positive (if it were negative the first character would not be a digit). That seems to be the case, since according to your comments it represents an electrical resistance.

Comment: I suppose that would work but take a look at the method, you see the y = x(1:2) should work, but the run yields an error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." userin = str2double(inputdlg( 'Please enter the resistance of the resistor (ohms):            ', 'Resistance' ));                                                        (REQUESTING THE USER FOR INPUT, THEN, )                                                                     userin = round(userin);
x = [ userin ]; y = x(1:2); But the "y" function yields an error message during the run such that the "Index exceeds matrix dimesnions."

Comment: Actually, I see what I did. I put the variable "userinput" into x from your suggestion, I did not put the actual number since I do not know them yet? This is why the y is yielding an error message because it's reading the user input as one value, it's not reading each character as it's own value like it otherwise would if the user-input would be stored as an array. (The user-input will always vary)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a string-based approach, but here is a mathematical solution to getting all of the digits:

```
>> x = 45697
x =

       45697

>> numDigits = floor(log10(x)+1)
numDigits =

     5

>> tens = 10.^(1:numDigits);
>> digitArray = fliplr(floor(mod(x,tens)./(tens/10)))
digitArray =

     4     5     6     9     7
```

The crux of this method is to use `mod` to chip off the high digits one at a time, shifting the new first digit down to the ones place, and finally truncating down to the get the integer value at that position.

In the case of the OP, the required values are `digitArray(1:2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in individual digits, you don't even need to invoke `str2num`. One way is enough as in `x_str = num2str(x);`, then you subtract `'0'` with `y = x_str(1:2)-'0';`.