# How can I combine numbers in a row into a single number

Tags: matlab, matrix

A = [7,2,3,4,4]

I want to combine them to:

B = 72344

I am new to matlab. Is there any build in function that can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
>> A = [7,2,3,4,4];
>> B=A*(10.^(length(A)-1:-1:0))'
B =  72344
```

Note @BenVoigt's comment:

```
>> A = [7,2,3,4,4;2,3,4,5,3]
A =

   7   2   3   4   4
   2   3   4   5   3

>> B=A*(10.^(length(A)-1:-1:0))'
B =

   72344
   23453
```

Comment: Yep, that looks better. No detour through string.

Comment: no need for `sum` and element-wise multiply, though.  A dot product would do the right thing.

Comment: As an added benefit, that will let you transform a whole bunch of numbers at once (each row of input will become a row of output)

Comment: To go the other way, mathematically, without strings, I posted [a similar MATLAB solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19745246/2778484). the other day that might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

```
    zz = str2num(num2str(A(:))')

zz =

       72344
```

is straightforward

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `num2str` and `strrep` as follows:

```
>> A = [7,2,3,4,4];
>> B = str2num(strrep(num2str(A(:)'),' ',''))
B =
    72344
```

Note that `A(:)'` is used to ensure a row vector.  However, webpat's answer is more concise since you can leave off the `'` and `strrep` is not required.  Also, the mathematical solution  by damienfrancois seem more elegant than using strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply add `'0'` as a shift into the range of numeric characters: `A+'0'`. Then, `B = str2double(char(A+'0'))`.