# MATLAB create a converter function (input: whole number) (output: string)

Tags: matlab, function, converters

In MATLAB, I want to create a function that takes input a whole number and output a string without using built-in functions such as num2str, int2str, or mat2str.
The whole number can possibly with a leading minus sign.
Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a fun homework assignment. Hint, check the output of `char(65:67)`, then `char(49:57)`.

Comment: There's always `sprintf('%d',x)`, but I assume that's off limits too.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is split up your number into individual digits and place them into an array.  Then, use [`char`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) to convert this numeric array into characters.  However, what you need to do is take each number and offset by 48.  The reason why is because `char` takes numbers stored into an array, and finds their ASCII equivalent characters mapped to these numbers and concatenates all of these characters into single string.  If you consult any [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll see that the characters from 0-9 get mapped to 48-57.

The first problem is to figure out how to split up your number into digits.  Check out my previous post on how to [extract the n<sup>th</sup> digit from a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960213/matlab-is-there-a-function-to-locate-an-n-digit-in-a-number-i-e-2nd-digit-in/26960510#26960510) in MATLAB.  This function only works with extracting one digit. In addition, this assumes that the number is **positive**.  We want to get all of the digits, and so you simply need to vectorize its use.  As such, what we will do for now is extract the digits out normally **disregarding the sign of the number**.   We do this by applying the absolute value function to this number, then apply the algorithm normally.  We can append a negative sign at the end of the algorithm should the number be negative.

With the algorithm that I wrote in the previous post, by vectorizing its use, a consequence to this is that each digit will be stored into an element in an array. Supposing your number was stored in `A`, we could extract out a numeric array like so:

```
numDigits = floor(log10(abs(A))) + 1; %// Calculate total number of digits seen in the number
n = 1 : numDigits; %// Place digits into individual elements in the array
d = numDigits - (n - 1);
out_seq = floor(mod(abs(A), 10.^d) ./ 10.^(d-1)); %// Note: Absolute value
```

Now the final step is to determine whether or not the number is negative.  If it is, we append a `-` sign to the string.  If not, just convert the number manually:

```
if A < 0
   out = ['-' char(out_seq + 48)];
else
   out = char(out_seq + 48);
end
```

---

Now, let's put this into a function to be complete:

```
function [out] = num_converter(A)

numDigits = floor(log10(abs(A))) + 1; %// Calculate total number of digits seen in the number
n = 1 : numDigits; %// Place digits into individual elements in the array
d = numDigits - (n - 1);
out_seq = floor(mod(abs(A), 10.^d) ./ 10.^(d-1)); %// Note: Absolute value

if A < 0
   out = ['-' char(out_seq + 48)];
else
   out = char(out_seq + 48);
end
```

---

Calling this function on a few of examples, this is what I get:

```
>> out = num_converter(669965)

out =

669965

>> class(out)

ans =

char

>> out = num_converter(-669965)

out =

-669965

>> class(out)

ans =

char

>> out = num_converter(-633)

out =

-633

>> class(out)

ans =

char

>> out = num_converter(63323)

out =

63323

>> class(out)

ans =

char
```

---

Also take note that I checked the class of each output when I ran the function.  As verified, they're all of type `char`, which is a string.

Comment: Nice explanation. +1 Great minds [think alike](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19745246/2778484) I guess.  ;)

Comment: @Kamtal - No problem at all!  I just didn't want you to get downvoted!

Comment: @chappjc - Woah!  I wrote that answer without knowing you wrote one that was similar... cool!